# Fetch only timestamp Date from the database

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, fetch

On my database under the staff_registered columns I have the date for example.

> 2013-11-26 01:24:34

From that same column I only want to get the date

> 2013-11-26

How can i do this? Thank You!

what i have tried is:

```
<?php echo $staffResults['date(staff_registered)']; ?>
```

Comment: echo date('m-d-Y H:i:s',strtotime($date_variable)); bases on your need you can edit `m-d-Y H:i:s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use date function :**

```
<?php
  $time = '2013-11-26 01:24:34'; //Assign your variable of datetime. 
  // may be it is like : $time = $staffResults['staff_registered'];
  echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($time)); //output: 2013-11-26
?>
```

**If you want to use `datetime` object then:**

```
<?php
  $time = '2013-11-26 01:24:34'; //Assign your variable of datetime. 
  $date = new DateTime($time); 
  echo  $date->format('Y-m-d'); //output: 2013-11-26
?>
```

Comment: output is coming as 1960-15-13   but in database it is todays date

Comment: Can you share your database date exact.

Answer (score 2):

Just use mySql date function as below

```
SELECT date(staff_registered), field2, field3 FROM ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date(t_stamp)` to get only the date part from a `timestamp`

Like in mysql try this

```
SELECT DATE('2016-10-15 01:02:03'); -> '2016-10-15'
```